# How do you hide a feature within a point layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point

I know this is basic, but for the life of me I can not remember how to hide/disable a specific feature point within a point layer. This seems like it should be a 2-3 click solution, but working with Arcmap I should always know better. One would think ESRI could simply make a right-click/hide point (polygon, or line), then have a "show all points in layer option" to bring it back.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.  I think I kind of see where your question is going, but, you really need to edit your question and elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to do this in ArcGIS Desktop, ArcGIS Server, ArcScene, etc...?  Also, what do you mean by "hide" do you want to just remove specific features from view in ArcGIS Desktop software temporarily... if so an answer explaining definition queries and potential solutions that way may be useful.  Do you have specific fields you're hiding on (ex: all with ProjectID of 42 need hidden)?  Please elaborate.

Comment: Definition query. To hide a feature whose objectid is 1: OBJECTID not in (1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first method : Select the feature that you want to hide, right click on the feature class--> selection > switch selection), right click on the feature class -->selection > create layer from selected features. Remove (or uncheck to make invisible) to old layer.

second method (needs information in the attribute table) : create a symbology with categories > unique values, remove the classes that you don't want to see and uncheck "all other values"

third method (also need information in attribute table) : right click on the layer > properties > definition queries, then write a SQL query to exclude your points.

fourth method (doesn't always work): go to the selection menu > selection option. Set the selection color identical to your background. The point "disappear" when you select them (unfortunately, with a transparent color the "normal" symbol is still visible, so this only work if your background is homogeneous)

Comment: To add to this answer, the user could also use page definition queries or a mask. I believe changing symbology or selecting features to be the quickest solutions, though.

Comment: I think the "Definition Query" option is the most simple & consistent method to use.

Comment: @RyanDalton except if you need to select using interactive selection tools because the information is not stored in the attribute table.

Comment: +1 For the crazy selection color idea.  Ridiculous hacks like that can only be the product of a frustrated ESRI user.

Comment: Symbology ended up being the easiest route. Thank you all for your input. I'm finishing up my GIS Cert. and working a summer intern job so some of the basic functions like to side-step my memory.